# InvalidProtocolBufferException when sending data from Python to Java

Tags: java, python, redis, protocol-buffers

I'd like to encode a protopuf in `python` and send it via redis to a `java` application where I `decode` it. 
Atm I can print the data in the `java` app and the values are correct. But everytime I receive data I get the following exception:

```
InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag
```

I tried it also with Jedis but the data was wrong there. Also tried to send it without the bytearray cast from python but I get the same error here.

Does anyone have an idea concerning this issue?

Code on `python` side:

```
tele_bytes = array("B")

// tele_bytes data comes from serial interface
tele_bytes[1] = ser.read()
tele_bytes[2] = ser.read()

raw_data = ''.join(chr(x) for x in [
                               tele_bytes[1],
                               tele_bytes[2]                                                   
                               ])

gw_id = '12345678'

reading = Reading_raw_data_pb2.ReadingRaw()

reading.timestamp = int(time())
reading.gw_id = gw_id
reading.raw_data = raw_data

reading_string = reading.SerializeToString()

r_server.lpush("testID", bytearray(reading_string))
```

Code on `Java` Side:

```
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis;
import protos.Reading4Java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleSubByte {

    public static Reading4Java.ReadingRaw trRaw = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinaryJedis binaryJedis = new BinaryJedis("test.id.local");

        while (true) {
            List<byte[]> byteArray = binaryJedis.brpop(0, "testID".getBytes());

            for (byte[] e :  byteArray) {
                // System.out.println(e);

                try {
                    trRaw = Reading4Java.ReadingRaw.parseFrom(e);
                } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(trRaw);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Protobuf file python:

```
package ttm

message ReadingRaw {
    required string gw_id = 1;      // gateway id (e. g. mac address)
    required bytes raw_data = 2;    // raw data from serial interface
    optional int64 timestamp = 3;   // timestamp of data reading from sensor device
}
```

Protobuf File for java:

```
package protos;

option java_outer_classname = "TireReading4Java";

message TireReadingRaw {
    required string gw_id = 1;      // gateway id (e. g. mac address)
    required bytes raw_data = 2;
    optional int64 timestamp = 3;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should add that the python side serializes a given value to a binary string. BRPOP on BinaryJedis Java side returns a List with byte[]. And I get the exception when I call: trRaw = Reading4Java.ReadingRaw.parseFrom(e)